# Moving every nth cell over nth columns

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I am trying to use VBA to write a script to move information from cell B2 to cell A1 and I can't figure out how to do so without explicitly typing out the information. This is not practical because I have 1200 cells to deal with and that would be 600 items to move. The code I have for doing this item by item is as follows:

```
Range("B2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("A2")
Range("B4").Select
Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("A4")
Range("B6").Select
Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("A6")
Range("A6").Select
```

Any suggestions on using a for loop or other method? Thank you.

Comment: In your question you want to write info from B2 to A1, but in your script it's B2 to A2. Which is which?

Comment: Sorry about that. I did mean B2 to A2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the same row you can try this:

```
For i = 2 To lastrow Step 2 '~~> supply last row here
    Range("B" & i).Cut Range("A" & i)
Next
```

This cuts B2 to A2 up to your last row of interest.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. Not sure why I couldn't figure out how to do this, maybe too much coding for the day.